# HTML find image for C# webBroswer from resources

Tags: c#, html, winforms, webbrowser-control

I'm showing an HTML file (Documentation.html)'s content inside a webBrowser control. The HTML file is located as resource.

```
string htmlFile = Properties.Resources.Documentation;
webBrowser1.DocumentText = htmlFile;
```

There is an image inside Documentation.html which will be shown properly in any browser:

```
<img src="Resources/Image.png">
```

Unfortunately all the text of the HTML-file appears normally but not the image.

Can I set the images path to the resources (like Properties.Resources.Image) or something else?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can embed the image's data in documentation.html file like

```
<img alt="Embedded Image" src="data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAADIA..." />
```

ref: 
[Embedding Base64 Images](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1207190/embedding-base64-images)

You can do it either direcly or even by code like

`htmlFile .Replace("Resources/Image.png", string.concat("data:image/png;base64," + imageData))`